# Sqlmap, All tested parameters do not appear to be injectable

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I am new to `SQLMAP`, I have been practicing with the Altoro Mutual portal which is a vulnerable portal, just enter the code `'OR 1 = 1 -` in one of its forms (Login) and we will obtain administrator access to the portal.

[Altoro M. Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egA3b.png)

```
sqlmap -u "https://demo.testfire.net/login.jsp" --data="uid=u&passw=p&btnSubmit=Login" --random-agent --cookie="JSESSIONID=154E7E124BE018261F6146682657A5EF" -method POST
```

As you can see, I define a cookie to facilitate access and enter the data sent by the form `uid = u & passw = p & btnSubmit = Login`. This information was obtained using BurpSuite.

[BurpSuite Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp3jt.png)

At the end of the execution, sqlmap reports that no fields are injectable:

[SqlMap Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhxnQ.png)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy/paste the text here and use the code formatting tools.

Comment: You could try to store the request in a file using burp  and use sqlmap with `-r` flag.As  example `sqlmap -r filename`. You could use `--level` and `--risk` to increase nmap checks . You could use the `--forms` flag too so sqlmap will check the login form automatically .

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have tried but I have the same result.